# Possible to have imported root template run first?

Tags: templates, xslt, import, document-root

Say you have these two xsl files:

*cow-wrapper.xsl*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="cow">
            <next-match />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*test.xsl*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="cow-wrapper.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- regular stuff to do -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case the root match in cow-wrapper.xsl is not called at all. Is there a way to make the root template match in cow-wrapper.xsl have presedence over the one in test.xsl?

What I'm after is a way to simply import a file and have it wrap the regular output. For example in a soap envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict), it looks like imported templates always have lower precedence than conflicting templates with higher import precedence (where the main XSLT would have the highest import precedence), but perhaps this is a suitable workaround?:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="cow">
            <apply-templates select="." mode="regular">
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="cow-wrapper.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="regular">
        <!-- regular stuff to do -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Was worried it could be something like that yes. Your workaround seems like an ok way to do it :)

Comment: @Svish One other potential option would be to leave your XSL the way you had it in your example and use `<xsl:template match="/*">` instead of `<xsl:template match="/">` in your main XSL.

Answer (score 1):

If I want the template in the imported template to be "executed" first, I would either not have a template in the importing stylesheet with the same match pattern, or I would write it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="cow-wrapper.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:next-match/>
        <!-- regular stuff to do -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Problem here is that cow-wrapper.xsl wouldn't be able to actually wrap the regular stuff to do as far as I understand. Whatever it did would appear in the output as a sibling of whatever you output as regular.

Comment: @Svish, You never specified in the question that "cow-wrapper.xsl should wrap the regular stuff ". So the problem is entirely in the way you present a question.

Comment: My apologies. Figured it would be kind of obvious from the name of the file :p I'll clarify the question.